# wisconsin protests

Tags: field, recording, crowd, trade

anyone recording these?  I'd be willing to trade some of my stuff for any of that.  thx!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed Rob Danielson has a track up on soundcloud
http://soundcloud.com/rob-d/20110222-1

Comment: This is amazing! He completely captured the energy of this inspiring movement. 
I wonder what his recording set up was. 
spectacular. 

Comment: "This is what democracy looks like!" That is my favorite chant in the piece! Thanks for the link. That was great work.

Comment: Wonderful recording of the National anthem! Very moving.